# How to open Sql2008 Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want To open Table By Sql 2008 Enterprise Manager Interface

As in Sql2005 Enterprise Manager Interface by Right Click then Click open Table.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the table in question and select "Edit Top 200 Rows".

The "200" is configurable from the **Tools\Options** dialog under "*SQL Server Object Explorer*"

Changing the value for "*Value for Edit Top  Rows command*" to **0** will return all rows for editing in a similar manner to "*Open Table*" in SSMS 2005.

You can also use **Ctrl+3** to display the underlying SQL after selecting "*Edit Top 200 Rows*" and manually change the query to customize which rows are show for editing.

Comment: I so need to remember this!  Damn, it has been 2 years since I answered this, how long has it been since I completely forgot this handy piece of information?

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature has been removed. Try the "Edit top 200 rows" command. It will do the same, but not fetch every row of a (potentially) huge table.